# Standardizing Image Size & Centering?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-scripting

I have over 500 images that I've collected online, but the issue is that they are all different sizes.

I am trying to standardize them to 500px by 500px to put as thumbnails on my blog, I was wondering if anyone knew a fast way to do this. I will keep the background white, but I just need the images to be resized and centered so it fits in a 500 by 500px canvas.

Would love some tips!

Answer (score 1):

Create an action.

Record the steps of opening the image, changing the Canvas Size to 500x500 px so that the new canvas extends evenly in all directions, save, and close. End your recording.

Then you can Batch process everything in that folder.